# Property of age undefined Khan Academy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var students = [
{
name: "Lexi",
age: 9,
math:31,
science:95,
english:100
},
{
name: "Zach",
age: 13,
math:97,
science:25,
english:92
},
{
name:"Evan",
age:13,
math:100,
science:100,
english:76
},
{
name:"Katelyn",
age:13,
math:99,
science:96,
english:97
},
{
name:"Lily",
age:13,
math:100,
science:95,
english: 97
}];
var sum =[];
for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
sum[j] = students[j].math+students[j].science+students[j].english;
}


println("Total sums of all 3 grades for Lexi, Zach, Evan, Katelyn, Lily are: 
" + sum);


var q = 0;
for(q=0;q<6;q++){
if(students[q].age > 10){
    println(students[q].name+ " is older than 10!");
}
}
var c = 0;
for(c=0;c<6;c++) {
if(students[c].math > 39){
    println(students[c].name + " is passing math!");
}
}
```

All of this works just tell me why I get that error message!

I can't seem to get this to work so why isn't it working?

Comment: Your second and third `for` loops iterate __6__ times, while in array you have __5__ elements.

Comment: There are only 5 students? There is no sixth one?!

Comment: You have 5 students. Including the 0 index it means that your indices when you're looping should be less than 5, not 6. When you're looking for students[5].age it returns an error because there is no students[5]. You should use `x < students.length` in your loop so you don't have to deal with knowing the limit of your arrays.

Comment: See also: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Comment: yeah thanks using students.length is really helpful because my teacher dude make us change stuff every 5 secs lol

Answer (score 0):

`println` is not a js method.Secondly instead of `q<6` & `c<6` do `q<students.length` & `c<students.length`

```js
var students = [{
    name: "Lexi",
    age: 9,
    math: 31,
    science: 95,
    english: 100
  },
  {
    name: "Zach",
    age: 13,
    math: 97,
    science: 25,
    english: 92
  },
  {
    name: "Evan",
    age: 13,
    math: 100,
    science: 100,
    english: 76
  },
  {
    name: "Katelyn",
    age: 13,
    math: 99,
    science: 96,
    english: 97
  },
  {
    name: "Lily",
    age: 13,
    math: 100,
    science: 95,
    english: 97
  }
];
var sum = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  sum[j] = students[j].math + students[j].science + students[j].english;
}


console.log("Total sums of all 3 grades for Lexi, Zach, Evan, Katelyn, Lily are: " + sum);
var q = 0;
console.log(students)
for (q = 0; q < students.length; q++) {
  if (students[q].age > 10) {
    console.log(students[q].name + " is older than 10!");
  }
}
var c = 0;
for (c = 0; c < students.length; c++) {
  if (students[c].math > 39) {
    console.log(students[c].name + " is passing math!");
  }
}
```

Comment: any reason for downvoting?

Comment: Because if this is a typo, vote to close, if you rather think that the OP does not understand whats wrong there, add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the variable `sum` with zero as initial value and the add the grades of each student.

Then you need to take the length of the array instead of a fixed number. This is important if the array changes.

```js
function println(s) { // i assume this is from the framework of the course
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}

var students = [
        { name: "Lexi", age: 9, math: 31, science: 95, english: 100 },
        { name: "Zach", age: 13, math: 97, science: 25, english: 92 },
        { name: "Evan", age: 13, math: 100, science: 100, english: 76 },
        { name: "Katelyn", age: 13, math: 99, science: 96, english: 97 },
        { name: "Lily", age: 13, math: 100, science: 95, english: 97 }
    ],
    sum = 0,
    j, q, c; // declare all variables in advance

for (j = 0; j < students.length; j++) { // take length of the array
    sum += students[j].math + students[j].science + students[j].english;
    // add all grades
}

println("Total sums of all 3 grades for Lexi, Zach, Evan, Katelyn, Lily are: " + sum);

for (q = 0; q < students.length; q++) { // take length of the array
    if (students[q].age > 10) {
        println(students[q].name + " is older than 10!");
    }
}

for (c = 0; c < students.length; c++) { // take length of the array
    if (students[c].math > 39) {
        println(students[c].name + " is passing math!");
    }
}
```